The ratio of the energy of the electromagnetic wave produced by the flow of current to the energy of the current flow itself
How to determine the ratio of the energy of an electromagnetic wave produced by a current flow to the energy of the current flow itself? What conditions must we take into account?
In general, it can be said that the energy of current flow is the kinetic energy of electric charge carriers (e.g. electrons), while the energy of the EM wave is related to the electromagnetic field generated by these carriers. I assume that to more precisely determine the ratio of these energies in a specific situation, it would be necessary to analyze the parameters of this situation and apply appropriate physical equations. This energy decreases with distance.
I just don't know what I should take into account.
Sorry for My English.

There is no simple relationship between current flow and EM generation.   EM radiation is created when charges are accelerated.
But non-accelerating moving charges (for example steady current in a linear wire) would not produce EM waves.

it can be said that the energy of current flow is the kinetic energy of electric charge carriers (e.g. electrons)

This is a description of kinetic inductance.   While present, magnetic inductance and the energy of the induced magnetic field is going to be more important for currents in a wire.
